# How can I wait in the .profile script until all devices are mounted?

Tags: mount, login, environment-variables, .profile

In my `.profile` script I want to export a variable *if* an external USB hardisk is mounted. I need this variable in later Perl scripts to determine if the device is mounted. Especially, if the device is not mounted, the later scripts behave differently.

Since these Perl scripts are also run in a Windows environment, I cannot simply check for the existence of the directory when the scripts are run. 
Also, the script run on different machines, some of which *sometimes* have  harddisk attached. When the harddisk is attached it won't be removed until the machine is shut down.

Besides, the scripts do their job perfectly and I'd rather not change them.

The device gets mounted to `/media/rene/DEVICE_NAME`.

In my home directory, I have a symbolic link to the mount point:

```
ln -s /media/rene/DEVICE_NAME ~/ext_hd
```

So, in my `~/.script` file I have the following test

```
if [[ -d ~/ext_hd ]]; then
   export device_mounted=yes
fi
```

Now, apparently, these lines are executed *before* the mount process is finished mounting the external harddisk. Thus, the variable `device_mounted` is not assigned.

So, is there a way to wait for the mount process to finish before I execute the test?

Answer (score 2):

How about running a script as a daemon?

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    if mountpoint -q /media/rene/DEVICE_NAME; then
        export device_mounted=yes
    else
        unset device_mounted
    fi
    sleep 30
done
```

*Edit:*

With the clarification in your edited question, we can simplify the script a bit:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    if mountpoint -q /media/rene/DEVICE_NAME; then
        export device_mounted=yes
        break
    fi
    sleep 30
done
```

Save that somewhere as e.g. `device-check.sh` and make the script executable:

```
chmod +x /path/to/device-check.sh
```

Then add this line in `~/.profile`:

```
/path/to/device-check.sh &
```

The trailing `&` character is essential. It makes the script start as a separate process, allowing the login process to continue.

After this the script starts at login and checks every 30th second if the device is mounted. If/when the script finds that the device is mounted, it sets the environment variable and ends.

Comment: I've never used a script as a daemon. Where and how would I start this script? Does `export ...` influence other unrelated processes?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger: Please consider the script as a draft, an idea. If you need more detailed help, I think you need to let us know more about the circumstances. How/when is the device mounted? Once mounted, will it keep being mounted through the session, or may it be unmounted later? What kind of machine are you running - desktop, server, ...? I'd suggest that you edit your question and try to cover those questions. (Setting or unsetting an environment variable does not affect already running processes. New processes which don't query that specific variable won't be affected either.)

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger: Answer edited.